# Add the count of select in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to run this SP but it is not working and giving error as

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_RECORDS_FORDATE

            @From_date Datetime,
            @To_date Datetime

            AS
            BEGIN


                SELECT * 
            INTO #temp 
            FROM ( 
                    select 0 SR_NO, 0 date, 0 Total, 0 Inward, 0 First_Level_Transfer, 0 Data_Entry_Transfer, 
                            0 Second_Level_Transfer, 0 Outward_Transfer,
                            0 Closed, 0 Communication_Transfer
                    from inward_doc_tracking_hdr
            ) AS x 


            select count(*) tot_count,'Total' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where 
            doc_date between convert(datetime, @From_date ,103) 
                and convert(datetime, @To_date, 103)  

            select count(*) tot_count,'Inward' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where
            doc_date between convert(datetime, '24/05/2016',103) 
             and convert(datetime, '26/05/2016', 103)  
             and status_flag in ('6')

            select count(*) tot_count,'1st Level Transfer' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where doc_date between convert(datetime, '24/05/2016',103) 
            and convert(datetime, '26/05/2016', 103)  
            and status_flag in ('4','26','24')

            select count(*) tot_count,'Data Entry Transfer' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where doc_date between convert(datetime, '24/05/2016',103) 
            and convert(datetime, '26/05/2016', 103)  
            and status_flag in ('15','20')

            select count(*) tot_count,'2nd Level Transfer' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where doc_date >=convert(datetime,'24/05/2016',103)
            and status_flag in ('17','21')

            select count(*) tot_count,'Outward Transfer' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr 
            where doc_date >=convert(datetime,'24/05/2016',103)
            and status_flag='18'

            select count(*) tot_count,'Close' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr  
            where doc_date between convert(datetime, '24/05/2016',103) 
                and convert(datetime, '26/05/2016', 103)  
            and status_flag='5'


            select count(*) tot_count,'Communication Transfer' stage from inward_doc_tracking_hdr 
             where doc_date between convert(datetime, '24/05/2016',103) 
                and convert(datetime, '26/05/2016', 103)  
            and status_flag='16'
  END


    SELECT * FROM #temp 
  END
```

I want to add the Count as per the column in temporary table  with SR_NO and date.

**NOTE** For time being i want to add for date between 24 - 26

I am using `sql-server-2005`

Comment: `select @Total = count(*), 'Total' stage, ...` - the first part there is trying to assign a value to a variable (like the error message says), the next part is trying to *return* a column value as part of a result set (data-retrieval). You're not allowed to do both in a single `SELECT`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I am updating my question in few minutes as what I want.. let me update it, may be then you will get an idea what I want

Comment: You should assign the @Total variable in a different SELECT statement

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sir, updated the question. kindly let me know how will I add the data into the temporary table of the count which I get. Do let me know if any doubts

Comment: your #temp table has a lot of row (one row for every row of inward_doc_tracking_hdr). Other selects are an unique value (aggregate by count). Please post your wished result.

Comment: @JoeTaras: See I want to show the result of `total`, `inward`, `...` with `sr_no` and the date column which will be `24-05-2016` to `26-05-2016`

Comment: I suppose in inward_doc_tracking_hdr you have, for example 100 SR_NO. Your SELECT INTO #temp has 100 rows. Other selects return an unique value (count under some conditions). How you want link 100 rows with unique value?

Comment: @JoeTaras: sorry went for call. see the Image for more info what I want.. I want to merge that data into the temp table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWNLo.png currently it is showing 0,0,0,0.all the above records are with actual data which needs to be added in that table

Comment: @JoeTaras: for SR_No it will be 1,2, 3 and for date it will be coming from `doc_date`, total will be `tot_count` etc.. Did u got the logic ??

Comment: I try to send a solution, tell me if it's ok

Comment: sure, waiting for it..

Comment: @JoeTaras: you post the answer, I will be back in 15mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood

Try this:

First step:

Creating of table #temp

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    date datetime, Total int, Inward int, First_Level_Transfer int,
    Data_Entry_Transfer int, 
    Second_Level_Transfer int, Outward_Transfer int,
    Closed int, Communication_Transfer int
)

INSERT INTO #temp
(date, Total, Inward, First_Level_Transfer,
    Data_Entry_Transfer, 
    Second_Level_Transfer, Outward_Transfer,
    Closed, Communication_Transfer)
SELECT
    doc_date, COUNT(*),
    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN status_flag = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag in ('4','26','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag in ('15','20') THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag in ('17','21') THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag='18' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN status_flag='16' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr
WHERE doc_date between @From_date and @To_date AND status_flag <> '6'
GROUP BY doc_date
```

I think, because you want counter, these are not linked with a single SR_NO.

Tell me if it's OK, otherwise we can tune the query

Comment: how to check the records but

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: i executed your query into my procedure. Now how to check that whether the query is correct or not. is it  `select * from #temp` ?

Comment: can u join me over here for more discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112985/sql-discussion

Comment: Yes, with select * from #temp

Comment: I'm in chat but I'm not authorized. Authorize me please

Comment: Have a nice day ;)

Comment: hi joe, are you their. need one small change in the procedure ?